# how to know which git branch triggered the jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins, github, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline Jenkins job which is working as expected, configured with the option **"GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling"** for auto build on any push to git repo.

I have hooked this Jenkins URL for multiple git repo's say `repo-A`, `repo-B`, `repo-B`.
Jenkins job is triggering automatically on any code pushes to these repo's.

But I would like to know which repo has triggered the Jenkins job as it is configured to multiple git repo's at Jenkins level. Any help on this highly appreciated.

Comment: You may refer to section *Environment variables* in jenkins online documentation: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

Comment: thanks for your help Timothy... i have tried to print below environment variables in my jenkins script which returns null always. **"env.GIT_BRANCH", "env.GIT_COMMIT" and "env.GIT_URL"**

Answer (score 2):

Following an example I found on Jenkins's bug tracker in one of the tickets (example stage), this is what works in my pipeline:

```
stage("checkout") {
  script {
    def git_params = checkout(...)
    println(git_params)
    env.REPO = git_params["GIT_URL"]
  }
}
```

`git_params` also included: `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`, `GIT_BRANCH`, `GIT_COMMIT`, `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`, `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`, `GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT`, `GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT`.

Comment: This is exactly what I shared in 2018. You added the "script" wrapper which allows declarative pipelines to use groovy code, like setting variables. Also instead of setting the result in an env variable, I would use a global field with @Field

Answer (score 1):

You can get [GIT Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) variables as a return value of step checkout

ie:

```
commit = checkout scm
println commit.GIT_URL
```

PS: your title should be "how to know which git **repository** and triggered the jenkins job". Indeed for getting a branch's name I would just get the value of `env.BRANCH_NAME`